# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined while updating geolocation values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, geolocation

I am trying to get latitude and longitude using geolocation. I got the value, but when I try to set state values, it shows me this error. "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined". Probably this error comes as I called setState inside another function.

I also tried to make another function for setting state values but it also throws this is not defined error. What is the right way of doing this?

```
getLocation=()=>
    {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        this.setState({venueLatitude:position.coords.latitude});
    this.setState({venueLongitude:position.coords.longitude});

      });
    }
```

Comment: i think problem is that you use this function outside the React component scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` isn't referring to the instance of the component. You can more read about it, example: https://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/deal-with-undefined-this-react-event-handler-performant-way/

```
getLocation = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.setState({ venueLatitude: position.coords.latitude });
        this.setState({ venueLongitude: position.coords.longitude });
    });
};
```